# App write query not working while fetching documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, appwrite

I am using appwrite for backend. I want to query out completed tasks. Here is the code:

```js
    const fetchTodos = async (type = 'all') => {
        let promise;
        if (type === 'all') {
            promise = databases.listDocuments(DATABASES_ID, COLLECTION_ID)
        } else if (type === 'active') {
            promise = databases.listDocuments(DATABASES_ID, COLLECTION_ID, [
                Query.equal('completed', false )
            ])
        } else {
            promise = databases.listDocuments(DATABASES_ID, COLLECTION_ID, [
                Query.equal('completed', [true])
            ])
        }

        promise.then(function (response) {
            setTodos(response.documents)
            console.log(response); // Success
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error); // Failure
        });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, I haven't added an index in to the document. For queries to work you need to create indexes for documents.

What worked?

I went to the appwrite console and in the indexes tab I created an index using the uid attribute as well as the complete attribute and that seemed to work.